# Covering for connected and locally path connected spaces

Tags: general-topology

Under the condition that the spaces (or maybe just the total) are connected and locally path connected, is then the a covering the same as a homeomorphism?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to ask?  As written, the answer is certainly not: consider for instance the covering map from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$.  In fact one almost always restricts to covering maps in which both the base and total spaces are connected and locally path connected.

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to ask is why a map of coverings f : E -> E' (p: E -> B and p' : E' -> B being coverings with p'f = f) is a map of coverings (mostly why it is surjective) under the condition that we are dealing with connected and locally path connected spaces. I thought that it might follow from what I asked above but you have proved me wrong.

Comment: Dear Down, To prove the surjectivity, you will have to use connectivity of $E'$ (otherwise the result is not true).  You want to show that $f(E) = E'$.  Here are some hints: (i) think about what properties you need to prove for $f(E)$ to get this equality.  (This is where connectedness will be used).  (ii) Prove them using the covering space properties.

Comment: Incidentally, this statement (that $E \to B$ is surjective) is also true if we are working with a fibration.  This is actually a hint: use path lifting.

Answer (score 7):

> Dear Down, To prove the surjectivity, you will have to use connectivity of $E'$ (otherwise the result is not true). You want to show that $f(E)=E'$. Here are some hints: (i) think about what properties you need to prove for $f(E)$ to get this equality. (This is where connectedness will be used). (ii) Prove them using the covering space properties.

– Matt E Sep 15 '10 at 18:49

> Incidentally, this statement (that $E\to B$ is surjective) is also true if we are working with a fibration. This is actually a hint: use path lifting.

– Akhil Mathew Sep 16 '10 at 2:41